# set element's style based on scrollbar visibility

Tags: javascript, css, webkit

I'm trying to create custom styles for a Textarea's scrollbar and resizer. Resizer should have two styles based on whether the scrollbar is visible or not.

This is what the resizer looks now:

[image]

Resizer styles are applied by adding a border to resizer with `webkit-resizer`

```
&::-webkit-resizer {
    border-right: 20px solid #c1c1c1;
    border-top: 20px solid #dddddd;
}
```

I would want to change the color of the `border-top` based on the scrollbar's visibility. White/transparent when the scrollbar is not visible and `#ddd` when the scrollbar is visible.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`ResizeObserver()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver)

> The ResizeObserver interface reports changes to the dimensions of an
> Element's content or border box, or the bounding box of an SVGElement.

```js
const textbox = document.querySelector('textarea')

new ResizeObserver(function() {
  textbox.classList.toggle('scrollable', textbox.scrollHeight > textbox.clientHeight)
}).observe(textbox)
```

```css
textarea::-webkit-resizer {
  border-right: 20px solid #c1c1c1;
  border-top: 20px solid #dddddd;
}

textarea.scrollable::-webkit-resizer {
  border-right: 20px solid #dddddd;
  border-top: 20px solid #c1c1c1;
}

textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #c1c1c1;
}
```

```html
<textarea>
A
B
C
D
E
F
</textarea>
```

Comment: Any tips on how to use this with react functional components? I tried to create the ResizeObserver in useEffect and the 'scrollable' class does indeed get appended to textbox.classList, but styles in textarea.scrollable doesn't get applied to the element.